# Regex for adding a class to links in text

Tags: php, regex

This a slice of code that I have taken from elsewhere on stackoverflow and modified it a tad. It adds a class to all links in a string:

```
// adds class of ah_link to outbound links,
// This is intended as for use with tracking clicks on outbound links
private function add_tracking_link($html) {
    // no extra class on these websites!
    $follow_list = array($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    return preg_replace('%(<a\s*(?!.*\brel=)[^>]*)(href="https?://)((?!(?:(?:www\.)?'.implode('|(?:www\.)?',$follow_list).'))[^"]+)"((?!.*\brel=)[^>]*)(?:[^>]*)>%', '$1$2$3"$4 class="ah_link ">',
        $html);
}
```

It works great but the issue arises if there is already a class in which case it merely doubles the attribute.

I was wondering if there is a way to just add a new class value to an already existing class attribute? This is way out of my regex safety zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strip out the class attribute first from the $html to be sure there is no additional class attribute and then do your regex, something like this:

```
$out = preg_replace('/(<a[^>]*?)(class\s*\=\s*\"[^\"]*?\")([^>]*?>)/','$1$3',$html);
$return = preg_replace(<your regex here>,'<your replacement class here>',$out);
```

i.e.:

```
$out = preg_replace('/(<a[^>]*?)(class\s*\=\s*\"[^\"]*?\")([^>]*?>)/','$1$3',$html);
return preg_replace('%(<a\s*(?!.*\brel=)[^>]*)(href="https?://)((?!(?:(?:www.)?'.implode('|(?:www\.)?',$follow_list).'))[^"]+)"((?!.*\brel=)[^>]*)(?:[^>]*)>%',
'$1$2$3"$4 class="ah_link ">',$out);
```